# How are cryogenic fuels and oxidizers generated and procured?

Tags: liquid-fuel, oxygen, hydrogen

I understand hydrogen can be generated from [steam-methane reforming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_reforming) or from electrolysis of water and then cooled to liquid through a series of cryogenic coolers. For steam reforming, the hydrogen needs to be separated by pressure swing adsorption, through a membrane, or through liquefaction since it has such a low boiling point of -252.9C. Oxygen just needs to be separated from air through cryogenic means with a boiling point of -183C compared to nitrogen's -195.8C.

I assume this is done on site, but which methods are actually practiced?

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9110/how-are-cryogenic-rocket-propellants-delivered-to-the-launch-pad) talks about the supplier, but doesn't go into the details of how it's produced (steam-reforming, electrolysis, etc.)

Comment: Edited to remove the part of the question discussed in the linked answer